# why does this throw a System.FormatException?

Tags: c#

Is this a bug on `string.Format` or what?

```
// Act
string l = "This is an UnitTest embedded resource.";
string r = "Please do not remove or change. Sincerely yours, {0}".FormatWith(model.Username);
string expected = "[\r\n\t{0}\r\n\r\n\r\n]\r\n{\r\n\t\r\n\t{1}\r\n\r\n}".FormatWith(l, r);
```

The `FormatWith` method is just an extension for syntactic sugar.

```
public static string FormatWith(this string text, params object[] args)
{
    return string.Format(text, args);
}
```

Comment: What are in model and model.Username?

Comment: What is `FormatWith`? It is not a BCL `string` extension method.

Comment: Could you paste the code of the FormatWith extension method?

Comment: Also, could you put the message of the exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with trying to use `{` and `}` in the format string. They need to be escaped or they will be treated as a format variable.

Change the last line to this:

```
string expected = "[\r\n\t{0}\r\n\r\n\r\n]\r\n{{\r\n\t\r\n\t{1}\r\n\r\n}}".FormatWith(l, r);
```